# Connect to wifi while hosting AP on another iface

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, iptables, wireless-access-point

I have two wireless interfaces. wlan1 and wlan0. And I want to host some Access Point on wlan1 (`airbase-ng` and `isc-dhcp-server`) and redirect packets from access point interface(`at0`) to `wlan0` which should be connected to some WiFi.
Here's my dhcp.conf

```
ddns-update-style none;
authoritative;
subnet 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0{
range 10.0.0.100 10.0.0.254;
option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;
option broadcast-address 10.0.0.255;
option routers 10.0.0.1;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
}
```

I've already used such config to redirect packets with `iptables` to `eth0` but now I need to do it with `wlan0`. Any ideas? I already tried `wpa_supplicant` but it seems that it doesn't work.

I'm running Debian 8 x64. PC is Asus s300ca and `wlan1` is TP-Link TL-WN722N
Original post is here: [stackowerflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33065795/connect-to-wifi-while-hosting-ap-on-another-iface#comment53950518_33065795)

Comment: Pls check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface on which `hostapd` is listening is in monitor mode, which makes it impossible to route the packets out of it directly. In fact, what you normally do is to put this interface into a bridge with the eth0 interface.

When you do not use an eth interface, you can still create a bridge with a virtual interface, say tap0, instead of eth0.

```
    ip tuntap add tap0 mode tap user root
    ip link set tap0 up
    ip link add br0 type bridge
    ip link set tap0 master br0
```

Now you can use the instruction `interface=br0` inside `hostapd.conf`. Next step, we use `br0` as the interface on which dhcp listens for requests. And lastly, you must both enable IPv4 packet forwarding to allow packets collected by hostapd to be routed thru wlan0, and use MASQUERADE:

```
    iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING  -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: Looks like smth right. But finally I've connected to some wifi point via wlan0 using dhclient and wpa_supplicant. I used `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE` to redirect